# show that $Y_n$ converges in distribution against a $U(0,1)$-distributed random variable

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of independent random variables, which have Laplace-distribution on the set $\{0,..,9\}$.
$Y_n:= \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \frac {1}{10^i}$ for all $n$.

now I want to show, that $Y_n$ converges in distribution against a $U(0,1)$-distributed random variable

I would be thankful for any help

Comment: (1) the [Laplace distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) usually describes a continuous distribution on the whole real line

Comment: (2) You presumably intend a uniform discrete distribution from $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ as without the $0$ you will not get your result

Comment: your are right, sorry! the 0 has to be included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider some $a \in [0, 1)$.  We want to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}[Y_n \le a] = a$.  We will denote $\lfloor a \rfloor_n$ to be $a$ floored to the nearest $n$th digit in its decimal representation.  It is clear then that $\mathbb{P}[Y_n \le a] = \mathbb{P}[Y_n \le \lfloor a \rfloor_n]$.  Let us write the decimal representation of $\lfloor a \rfloor_n$ as $0.a_1a_2\ldots a_n00000\ldots$  Since each of the $X_i$ are i.i.d. and discrete uniform, it is clear that each $Y_n$, written as, $0.x_1x_2\ldots x_n 0000 \ldots$ with $x_j \in \{0, \ldots, 9\}$ is equally likely.  Therefore, $\mathbb{P}[Y_n \le \lfloor a \rfloor_n]$ is precisely the number of integers less than or equal to $a_1a_2\ldots a_n$, which is  $\lfloor a \rfloor_n$.  Therefore, 
$$ \mathbb{P}[Y_n \le a] = \lfloor a \rfloor_n$$
Taking limits on both sides we have,
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}[Y_n \le a] = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lfloor a \rfloor_n = a$$

Comment: I´m not really sure why this answeres my question correctly. Where did you use the definition of Yn and why is this showing convergence in distribution?

Comment: $Y_n$ is simply a decimal such that the $j \le n$ digit of $Y_n$ is equal to $X_j$, which is uniform on $\{0, 1, \ldots, 9\}$.  The definition of convergence in distribution is that the CDF of $Y_n$ converges pointwise at all points of continuity (which for the uniform 0-1 case, is just proving that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}[Y_n \le a] = a$ for all $a \in [0, 1]$).